# Django ModelForm exclude required many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have these models

```
class Team(models.Model):

    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d',null=True)
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name="team_admins")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name="team_members")
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES,default='M')


    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):             
        return self.title  

class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone=models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=15)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.user.username
```

The User shall be able to create a new Team. I want the user who created the team to be an admin of the team automatically. He can later add other users as admins. So I did this in my form and view.

```
class TeamForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Team
        exclude = ['created_date', 'modified_date', 'admins']

def CreateTeam(request):
    user=request.user
    prof=user.profile
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=TeamForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            t = form.save(commit=False)
            t.admins= prof
            # I also tried this
            # t.admins.add(prof)
            t.save()
            form.save_m2m()


    form=TeamForm()
    return render(request, 'create_team.html', {'form' : form})
```

I get this error `"<Team: X>" needs to have a value for field "team" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

How do I fix this?  Is there a better way for automatically adding the user who created the team to the admins? and also do I need a Through parameter for the many to many fields?

Comment: No that isn't the case at all. If I wasn't retrieving the profile correctly I would've got another error. Plus I don't have a get_profile method.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal `get_profile` has been deprecated since 1.5 and is fully removed from 1.7 onwards. Even before that, there was absolutely no need to use it if you knew the related name for the profile: it was a very thin layer around `user.<profile_related_name>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
if form.is_valid():
    t = form.save()
    t.admins.add(prof)
```

Comment: To clarify this: the `Team` needs to exist in the database _before_ you can save a foreign key to that object (which a many-to-many relation does). That's why you should first save the team and only then add the admin.